# Drawable.createFromPath is null

Tags: android, load, save, drawable

I am getting null object when doing **Drawable.createFromPath**

Here is how I save it to file

```
public void saveDrawableToFile(Drawable d, String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = pictureDrawable2Bitmap((PictureDrawable) d);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
```

I've checked in DDMS, file really exists (/data/com/pg/svgz/files/2.png).

This is how I save and load it

```
saveDrawableToFile(d, "2.png");
Drawable d1 = Drawable.createFromPath("2.png"); 
Drawable d2 = Drawable.createFromPath("/2.png"); 
Drawable d3 = Drawable.createFromPath("com/pg/svgz/2.png"); 
Drawable d4 = Drawable.createFromPath("com/pg/svgz/files/2.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

try /data/com/pg/svgz/files/2.png or /mnt/data/com/pg/svgz/files/2.png